# Total boundedness and compactness in $\ell^\infty$

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, normed-spaces

An exercise that I am trying to tackle goes like this

$\ell^\infty$ defined as usual and a subset $S= \{ (x_n):|x_n| \leq \frac1n  \text{ for all n}\}$

**a) Prove that S is closed (Done, fairly straighforward)**

**b)Prove that S is totally bounded**

(Hint: $\forall \epsilon>0, \text{consider the finite set } B_{\epsilon}=(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\Bbb Z)\cap [-1,1] \text{ and prove that } $

$S_{\epsilon}=\{(y_n): y_n\in B_{\epsilon} \text{ and } y_n=0 \text{ }  \forall n>N_\epsilon\}\cap  S $ is an $\epsilon$ -net for $S$ if $N_\epsilon$ is sufficiently large)

**c) Prove that S is compact (can use that $\ell^\infty$ complete)**

So part c) will be given after we have a) and b) since totally bounded and closed will imply that its compact (with some intermediate steps). I am not sure how to use the $\epsilon$-net hint that we are given.

$$\text{A subset of X and let }\epsilon>0 \text{ a finite set }A_\epsilon\text{ is an } \epsilon \text{-net} \text{ for A if A} \subset \cup_{x\in A_\epsilon}B^o(x,\epsilon)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea I think is pretty simple. Take $\epsilon > 0$. Take $N = N(\epsilon)$ so that $\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$. Then if we just look at sequences which are $0$ from the $N^{th}$ coordinate on, the $L^\infty$ norm will be less than $\epsilon$ from any sequence in $S$, if we just consider the terms from the $N^{th}$ coordinate on. So we just need to worry about the first $N-1$ coordinates. And we can cover take care of these (with an $\epsilon$ of error) with only finitely many sequences. For the first coordinate, divide $[0,1]$ into $N$ equal pieces $I_1^{(1)},\dots,I_N^{(1)}$. Then for the second coordinate, divide $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ into $N$ equal pieces $I_1^{(2)},\dots,I_N^{(2)}$. Etc until the $(N-1)^{st}$ coordinate. Then your $\epsilon$-net will be $(x_1,\dots,x_N,0,0,0,0\dots)$ where $x_1,\dots,x_N$ range over all the centers of the intervals $I_{j_1}^{(1)},I_{j_2}^{(2)},\dots,I_{j_N}^{(N)}$, respectively.

Comment: Could you, perhaps, also explain how one is suppose to use $B_{\epsilon}=(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\Bbb Z)\cap [-1,1]$ for this question? I can see the intuition but that part is just beyond me

Comment: The $B_\epsilon$ is the same as chopping up the interval into $N$ pieces. I recommend you read and understand my solution before trying to fit in the pieces you were given.

Comment: Why is the $\epsilon$ net 1 single sequence in your answer? An epsilon net is a finite set. Round brackets mean sequences from what I know

Comment: The $\epsilon$-net is the finite set consisting of the sequences I described

Comment: So from what I understand, the epsilon net you defined will contain the centers of all the divisions of our interval. So it can also be the set of centers of all the open balls of radius $\epsilon/2$ and then for every „coordinate“ of a sequence in $\ell^\infty$ $d(x,y)<\epsilon$ for all the terms up to $N_\epsilon$. Is my thinking okay?

Comment: Yes, and we are also fine for all terms past $N_{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Yes because the fixed an $N_\epsilon$ which takes care of it. Correct?

Comment: Correct. Everything is $0$ after $N_\epsilon$ in our net and any sequence we would approximate by has terms less than $\epsilon$ (away from 0) after the index $N_\epsilon$.

Comment: @Newphonewhothis are you content with my answer now?

Comment: Yes, after drawing a few diagrams everything is okay. Thank you for the help!